# Error in spring mvc: class <> nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb, javax

My Response object like below:

```
public class ValidationResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "success")
    private boolean success = true;
    @XmlElement(name = "message")
    private Object message;
}
```

Users class:

```
public class Users {
    @XmlElement(name = "user")
    @JsonProperty("users")
    private List<User> userList;
}
```

When I try to produce "application/xml", I got exception as below:
com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class com.abcd.dao.domain.user.Users nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.abcd.dao.domain.user.Users nor any of its super class is known to this context.

How to handle the "Object" type in the response class in spring mvc:  ? 
Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding @XmlSeeAlso its working as expected:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Users.class, User.class})
    public class ValidationResponse {
}
```

Thanks